# Getting a .png image by Apache HttpClient on Android

Tags: java, android, png, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to get a .png file to render in a WebView after getting the file through an apache HttpClient get request. I'm actually reading the HttpResponse contents into a simple byte array -> (evaluating the contents into a String when debugging).

It appears if I convert those bytes into a string to compare with the actual file, they look different. Is there a specific way to retrieve .png file
 using the apache HttpClient?

*example compare, my test is on the left and actual file on right*

[image]

Comment: the difference in the number of chars you see are because of surrogate pairs encoding of unicode characters. Have you tried to display the image?

Comment: Unfortunately, I see the the empty outlined box in Chrome. Your comment has triggered me to suspect it's probably an encoding issue.

Comment: how are you trying to display the image. WebView makes me thing you have some html on the device with a <img> tag you can just set the url and refresh. why handle downloading the image yourself?

Comment: It's a long story! :-) .  The short version is, I wrote a proxy server for the webView, and one of the sticking points are .png files. the image files are coming through the html content as <img src="proxyserver:port/url/domain.com/images/*.png" type format

Comment: does it work if you put the url for the origin server? is this proxy a server that was created and handles specific paths differently or does it just forward the requests and responses. when and why are you looking at the bytes. you really need to provide the code that is processing the data. the screencap of the string values is not too useful in that regard.

Comment: I discovered the problem. I'm using a third party api that is essentially a wrapper around httpClient. That wrapper has a bug, even though it's documented to behave the same as the apache httpClient. Thanks so much for your insight, your question sparked me to look at the problem differently.

Comment: is it Jetty? of a particular version.

Comment: if it is a way that i resolved a similar issue was to getBytes of the string and send that as the response because regular java getBytes on the string does the right conversion and then the response can send it without encoding.

Comment: It's some small cloud security provider. They fixed the API and I was able to get the byte array to stream out fine. Thanks again Mavriksc. :-)